# jQuery, compare content before loading

Tags: php, jquery, html

How would I go around updating a divs content, if the old content and the new content aren't the same. Only update if it's the same. As in, let's say. Currently I have this:

```
<div style="min-height:200px;max-height:220px;height:auto;overflow-y:auto;padding:2px;" class="main">

<?php include("ajax/display_messages.php");?>

</div>

$(setInterval(function() {

$('.main').load('ajax/display_messages.php',

function(response, status, xhr){ });

}, 2000));
```

Is there any way to make it check the contents first? Before updating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
var $main = $('.main');
$.get('ajax/display_messages.php', function (data)
{
    if ($main.html() !== data) $main.html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(setInterval(function()
{
    $.get('ajax/display_messages.php',function(response)
        { 
            if( $('.main').html() != response ) 
            { 
                $('.main').html(response);
            }
        });
}, 2000));
```

Comment: Nope. The callback fires after the HTML has already been set.