# jQuery, update content when necessary

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get, load

I'm trying to update contents of a chat located in div (div1) but only when the contents of div1 change (a message was submitted into db and picked up in div1).

I tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906797/jquery-compare-content-before-loading) but my get fails to compare the data.

This solution works perfectly but without content comparison:

```
window.onload = startInterval;
function startInterval()
{
    setInterval("startTime();",2000);
}

function startTime()
{
    jQuery('#div1').load('index.php #div1 > *');
}
```

This is the modification based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906797/jquery-compare-content-before-loading), which fails:

```
window.onload = startInterval;
function startInterval()
{
    setInterval("startTime();",2000);
}

function startTime()
{
    var $main = $('#div1');
    $.get('chat.php #div1', function (data)
    {
        if ($main.html() !== data) $main.html(data);
    }); 
}
```

I tried various modifications of this code but to no avail... 
I can't reload the entire page and I don't want to do this if not necessary since it makes the chat harder to read if you have to scroll trough the messages. 
How can this be fixed?

**UPDATE**

Based on @T.J's suggestions I modified the code which now works perfectly:

```
window.onload = startInterval;
function startInterval()
{
    setInterval(startTime,3000);
    scrolDown();
}

function startTime()
{
    var $main = $('#div1');     
    $.get('#div1', function (data)
    {
        elements = $(data);
        thisHTML = elements.find("#div1").html();
        if ($main.html() !== thisHTML) {                
            $main.html(thisHTML);
            scrolDown();
        }           
    });     
}
```

The other problem was that get required library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
```

which apparently was not required by the load which I used previously.

Comment: Side note: Don't pass strings into `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. Use `setInterval(startTime,2000);` (passing a function reference), not `setInterval("startTime();",2000);` (passing a string).

Comment: Your first (successful) attempt pulls from index.php, the second unsuccessful pulls from chat.php, are these the correct pages?

Comment: Those pages should be the same, It’s just a mistake I made while simplifying the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `get`, but you want the fragment feature of `load`, so you'll have to do that work yourself. Then remember what you got last time, and only update if it's not the same:

```
var lastHTML;

function startTime()
{
    var $main = $('#div1');
    $.get('chat.php', function (data) // <== Or index.php, the question has both
    {
        var elements, html;

        // Turn the HTML into elements
        elements = $(data);

        // Get the HTML of *only* the contents of #div1
        html = elements.find("#div1").html();

        // If that has changed, use it
        if (lastHTML !== thisHTML) {
            lastHTML = thisHTML;
            $main.html(thisHTML);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Note that that's a fairly basic implementation of the fragment feature (it doesn't, for instance, strip out scripts the way `load` does). You may want to look at how `load` does its fragment stuff and replicate that (the joy of open source).

Comment: Thank you for your time, but the problem is probably somwhere else aswell since I cant even run alert('test') from inside of the get (works well outside of it). My entire code: http://pastebin.com/fjWHHiu7 its a modification of a joomla module. The full path to the site is www.example.com/index.php/sim-chat

Comment: @Roman: Fundamentally, if `load` works, `get` will work. I think it must be that you're changing some *other* variable at the same time you're switching from `load` to `get`.

Comment: @"T.J." could you please take a look at the entire code? http://pastebin.com/fjWHHiu7 I'm really out of ideas after few hours of struggling with it... The first part of the startTime() function (in comments) is the one working fine - without content check.

Comment: @Roman: Code should always be on SO, not external sites, for various reasons. I did take a look, and presumably `sim-chat` is not a valid relative URL from the page on which this is running, so the request fails, so naturally the success callback is not called. Look in the JavaScript console for errors, and look at the `error` function in `$.ajax` (`$.get` is just shorthand for `$.ajax`, see [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) for how to turn `$.get` into `$.ajax` so you can use all the options0.

Comment: That link was ok, the other problem was caused by a missing js library. Thank you!